# Excel Formula if the value of a cell in one column stays the same but the value in another changes then show me

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I hope you can help. In Screen Shot 1. You can see that the number 4424383
in column Y appears 6 times from row 2 to row 7

In column U you can see the numbers 12345 and 76259 and they also appear from rows 2 to 4 and 5 to 7

What I need is a formula that can produce a piece of text that says "Investigate" in column Z, if the number in Column Y stays the same but the number in Column U changes.

If you look at Screen Shot 1 you will see the green number 4417458 in column Y and the green number 76260 in column U this DOES NOT need to be investigated.

Like wise with the purple numbers

Its only when the HUB_PARTY_ID or Y number continues to be the same but then the MTNG_ATNDEE_ID or U column number changes that I need "investigate" to appear in the Z column.

as always any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Screen Shot 1[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
=IF(Y2=Y1,IF(U2<>U1,"Investigate","Cool"),"Cool")
```

Comment: BOO YAAH!! :-) Thank you so much much Zipa simple and effective. Much respect from Dublin :-) I hope you have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below formula starting with the third row of column Z

```
=IF(AND(Y3=Y2,U3<>U2),"Investigate","NA")
```

Result:

[image]